# Symfony Messanger getPathInfo() on null error

Tags: symfony, symfony-messenger

some one help me for that when I save a new que data then I runned command but I get this error failed: Call to a member function getPathInfo() on null what is the problem ?
What I doing wrong or missing ?`

```
<?php

namespace App\Message;

class POGenerateClickSaveMessage {

    private $itemId;
    private $lastStatus;


    public function __construct($itemId, $lastStatus){
        $this->itemId = $itemId;
        $this->lastStatus = $lastStatus;
     }


    public function getItem()
    {
        return $this->itemId;
    }
    public function getItemId(){
        return $this->itemId;

    }

    public function getLastStatus(){
        return $this->lastStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you call getPathInfo()?